# Ampere boosting circuit

Tags: amperage

I'm trying to solve a problem in a device where I don't have much room for a stronger power supply, but I have room for some small circuit board "to fly in the air".

I need a circuit that amplifies amperage (not voltage) and can't find it. Just simple basic idea how to made this works.

The voltage I have is 12V/1A and I need 12V/3A. Should I use some voltage booster that raises the voltage and then lower it to a lower one?

An external power supply also makes no sense, because then I have other problems with the installation.

Comment: It is possible just temporary to get 3A out of 1A. Example: if load drains 0.5A most of the time and then from time to time drains 3A this additional energy can be covered from capacitor.

Comment: Do you need 12V * 3A = 36 watts continuously? If so, forget it. But, if you only need that power with less than 30% duty cycle, you can store the energy at low power for a long time, then release it at high power for a short time. However, if you don't have much room, then you're not going to be able to store much energy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't find what you need because making it would break the current laws of physics and that's not simple.

You have 12V 1A supply and need 12V 3A.

It is impossible with the current laws of physics to make a 12W power supply to output 36W. Anything that indicates such magic is possible is a scam, free energy does not exist.

Comment: Trust me, I didn't even think about free energy :) I am literally in a problem that I need a stronger power supply in the device. I will have to somehow hook up the current supply, change the inductor and components to give me a higher amps.

Comment: Finding a more powerful power supply of the same physical size is going to be far easier than attempting to modify a switchmode supply without blowing something up and/or hurting yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, you can't put 12W in and get 36W out.  If there was such a device, everyone would would want one.

You can increase voltage and lower current, or lower voltage and increase current, but you cant do both at the same time.  You will be getting free energy.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think about free energy, just have a problem with power supply.